# process post data from ajax post with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, request

I set up a simple ajax request with jquery ajax to post a string to a php script (php newbie).

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/server.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: imgname,      
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    error: function ( xhr, textStatus, thrownError ){
        console.log(thrownError);           
    },complete: function( jqXHR ){
        console.log("yeah", jqXHR)  
    }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
$ajaxData = gettype($_POST['data']); 
echo $ajaxData;
?>
```

PROBLEM:

I get a state 200 OK. And in the request header I can see my String posted right. But the response is empty, with the notification.

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: uploadfilename in **C:\xampp\htdocs\webwiese\dragdropUpload\php\fileserver.php** on line **2**

If I echo a simple string "per hand" it works fine, but how can I "catch" my data from the ajax post?
THX

Comment: imgname is a string .. like tree.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You "catch" your data from the PHP page. Then you return the correct headers as necessary to the AJAX page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one--
AJAX:-

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/server.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: imgname, 
    dataType: "text",
     success:function(response){
     },
     failure:function(response){
        alert("there is an error.");
     }
});
```

PHP:-

```
<?php
   $ajaxData = gettype($_POST['data']); 
   echo $ajaxData;
?>
```

Comment: yes I tried this one - it echoes NULL. but in my post headers my imagename is sent as e.g. tree.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/server.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: imgname,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",      
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    error: function ( xhr, textStatus, thrownError ){
        console.log(thrownError);           
    },success: function( jqXHR ){
        console.log("yeah", jqXHR)  
    }
});
```

you should define mimetype while working with files in the form. if not working then please add your form  code here.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My post is 5 years old and I do not have access to that code anymore :-) I am doing sth different nowadays. I'll consider deleting the question, as there wasn't an answer that helped back then and we cannot test yours now. Thete will be no value to future readers of this question.. Thanks again and happy new year.

Comment: It will be useful to other developers, so I answered this question. I was looking for the same solution few months back and solved it with the help of blogs. you can mark this as solved so others can take benefit. Happy new year